# Conditional Regex Substition in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex like this

```
value = ">>897897"
rep = "<div> \\1 </div>"
pat = "&gt;&gt;(\\d+)"
res = re.sub(pat, rep, value)
```

But now I want to add a condition that when the number equals a certain number, like 50, it uses a different substition.

For example if match equals 50:

use

```
rep = "<p> \\1 </p>"
```

instead of

```
rep = "<div> \\1 </div>"
```

Comment: First get the matched digits then based in its value call next regex to replaced it with desired one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use a function as replacement and do the conditional checks there:

```
def check(match):
    g = match.group(1) # group(1) or any group number you have
    if g == '50':
        return '<p>%s</p>' % g
    else:
        return '<div>%s</div>' % g

res = re.sub(pat, check, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function instead of a replacement pattern in re.sub. The function will be passed the match object. So for example:

```
re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda m: "-" + m.group(0) + "-" if m.group(0) != "50" else "*"+m.group(0)+"*", "a 50 b")
# gives 'a *50* b'
re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda m: "-" + m.group(0) + "-" if m.group(0) != "50" else "*"+m.group(0)+"*", "a 64 b")
# gives 'a -64- b'
```